# decimal test with dotnet on ubuntu

Tags: c#

I tried to the print the minimum and maximum value of decimal type as follows:

```
decimal decmin = decimal.MinValue;
decimal decmax = decimal.MaxValue;

Console.WriteLine($"The range of the decimal type is: {decmin} and {decmax}");
```

The output is as follows:

```
The range of the decimal type is: -79228162514264337593543950335 and 79228162514264337593543950335
```

But according to the documentation

"The decimal type has a smaller range but greater precision than double"

Does the output look so ?

Comment: Yes it does. Do you think it doesn’t? What is your actual question?

Comment: It seems to me that it has bigger range than double

Comment: Double can go up to 1.7E308. I’d say those numbers are a lot less. Decimal goes to 7.9E28, so its range is less than a tenth of a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Console.WriteLine($"The range of the decimal type is: {decimal.MinValue} and {decimal.MaxValue}");
// The range of the decimal type is: -79228162514264337593543950335 and 79228162514264337593543950335
```

That's -7.9228162514264337593543950335E+28 and 7.9228162514264337593543950335E+28

Doing the same for double however.

```
Console.WriteLine($"The range of the double type is: {double.MinValue} and {double.MaxValue}");
// The range of the double type is: -1.79769313486232E+308 and 1.79769313486232E+308
```

So you see, the range of double is approximately 280 orders of magnitude (or 10^280) larger than the range of decimal